# How can I make lined paper using Microsoft Word?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2011

I have a small personal project that I need lined writing paper for; though, I don't want to use notebook paper.
So my question to you is: How can I make lined paper using Microsoft Word?

Btw, I'm running Microsoft Word for Mac 2011.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/lined-paper-TC030005376.aspx). It has templates for lined paper. The one line description is: "If you ever need some lined paper but theres none to be found, try this!".

This template is for Windows operating system.

Comment: I wanted to create my own template though, because that isn't exactly what I want. How do I create a template?

Comment: You would have to manually draw the lines, make sure the spacing is good, etc, then save it as a template (*.dotx).

Comment: To help with manually creating the lines, toggle on the gridlines in `View > Gridlines`

Comment: Thanks :) What would I use to make the lines? (Sorry, really new to office)

Comment: You could draw the lines using the line object from the drawing toolbar. Make one, copy it. Then after its been lined up, copy both of the lines, and paste, space it correctly, and repeat (this time 2 lines at a time), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with a single column and as many rows as you want to fill the page then apply a border format of your choice to the bottom of each table cell.

Comment: That would get pretty annoying if you want the lines to flow naturally as you type.

Comment: @soandos, the OP states "I don't want to use notebook paper." so I presume he wants to to hand write on the printed paper.

Comment: Ah, ok, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Whnever I need the odd bit of lined or graph paper, I make it at this site - you end up with a PDF so you can reprint offline anytime:

http://incompetech.com/graphpaper/

The options for each type of paper are very customisable and it can generate many different types.